# How to click a button on pop uo URL in jmeter without recording the script so that a data can be saved in the application

Tags: jmeter

i have a web application which has confirmation pop up to save a record . i have used post on the HTTP request sampler and used parameter body , but still the record is not getting saved in the web application using jmeter . i have to click save then yes on the confirmation pop up
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't actually perform "clicks", it sends [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), in your case this "popup" seems to be used for populating the `USER_COMMENT` section:

[image]

with regards to "record is not getting saved in the web application"  - it indicates that your script fails somewhere somehow, you should inspect response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, it might be the case the application will tell you what's wrong with your request.

The most common reasons are:

1. Your login request fails hence all subsequent requests are landing at the login page. JMeter automatically treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful therefore you can see them as "green" or false-positive so check that all previous responses return expected data using the aforementioned View Results Tree listener
2. The request may fail due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/), i.e. you're updating the record which was created during recording instead of adding a new one